# JSON Schema draft5 VS JSON Schema draft4

Tags: json, jsonschema

What are the features added as a part of `JSON Schema` draft5, which are not presented in `JSON Schema` draft4

Answer (score 1):

None, just some language improvements and clarification. draft 6 will be different.

Answer (score 1):

The intention with the October 2016 publication was to update references and fix inconsistent behavior, while being backwards-compatible with the existing draft-04 meta-schema. New features were withheld for a future publication and the next meta-schema.

The next meta-schema release, and associated drafts, will likely be called draft-05 and will likely introduce changes to how "format" "exclusiveMinimum" and "exclusiveMaximum" are handled, addition of several keywords "examples" "contains" and "const", changes to Hyper-schema, and probably other features currently being debated.